# 3 column layout - 100% height sidebars, auto height container with no faux columns

Tags: html, css

A common problem I'm sure but with a slight twist.

Normally I'd just use faux columns and have no issues, but the design I'm currently creating is three columns, but if the right or left column is not there, the center column should fill their width.

Any ideas or links to articles on solutions for this? I've seen a lot but nothing with quite the same situation.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what css structure you're aiming for. 
Fixed-width columns either side (height:100%), and variable-width/height content in the middle?

```
body {padding-left:ABCpx; padding-right:ABCpx; margin:0 auto;} #columnLeft {height:100%; width:ABCpx; position:fixed; left:0; top:0} #columnRight {height:100%; width:ABCpx; position:fixed; right:0; top:0}
```

Comment: EDIT: 'right:ABCpx;' on columnRight should have been 'right:0;'. Tried and working, hope thats what you were looking for!